# ViewPager getChildAt() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using ViewPager in my activity and it only has two fragments, both implemented in similar structure as follow, so there should always be a fragment returned when getInstanced is called:

```
public class ListReminderFragment extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    private static ListReminderFragment listReminderFragment;

    public static ListReminderFragment getInstance() {
        if(listReminderFragment != null)
            return listReminderFragment;
        else {
            listReminderFragment = new ListReminderFragment();
            return listReminderFragment;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main_screen, container, true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return ListReminderFragment.getInstance();    // temporary
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
}
```

And I am initialising my ViewPager as below, in OnCreate() in the activity that has the ViewPager:

```
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

But when I call viewPager.getChildAt(), viewPagerAdapter.getItem(0).getView(), they both return null,

when I call viewPager.getChildCount(), it returns 0 instead of 2.

How should I access the views in side the fragment in ViewPager?

Comment: By the way, I tried a lot of other methods that I could found on this site, none of them worked for my case, so sorry for possible replication.

Comment: "How should I access the views in side the fragment in ViewPager?" -- put that code in `onCreateView()` and/or `onViewCreated()` of your `ListReminderFragment`. You would do that after getting rid of the `static` instance of that fragment, when you modify `getInstance()` to always return a new instance.

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean put that code in onViewCreated()? What code? I need to have interactions between these views and views in the parent activity. What kind of code should I put there?

Comment: "I need to have interactions between these views and views in the parent activity" -- your interactions should be between the activity and the fragments. The fragments manage communications with their views that they manage. "What code?" -- the code that works with a fragment's views should be in the fragment itself.

Comment: So the proper way of implementing interactions between activities and fragments are interfaces?

Comment: Corey Latislaw explains how to communicate between activities and transitions in this [presentation](https://prezi.com/fh2uslbr1xs3/the-fragment-transition/)

Comment: That's certainly one approach. There are others (e.g., event buses).